# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8

Tags: android, arrays

hi dear here I am posting my whole class where I am getting problem. First I explain my problem. I am generating an arrayList "Items" using spinners and the elements in spinners and arrays are exactly same then After comparing array length and ArayList size I want to jump on next activity but problem is occoured in comparing arrays now please help me for this problem
Thanks here is my activity

```html
package com.example.mine4.pantryrecipes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class AddItem extends Activity {
    MultiSelectionSpinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3,spinner4;
    Button button1;
    TextView tv;
    private int count = 0;
    List<String> Items=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> veg=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> spice=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> dairy=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> subset = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] arrayRecipe = { "chicken","vegetable oil","ginger",
            "onion", "garlic","potatoes","tomatoes","roasted peanuts", "peanut butter"};
    String[] arrayRecipe2 = { "chicken","garlic","vegetable oil", "tomatoes",
            "Dijon mustard","breadcrumbs","Parmesan cheese","unsalted butter"};
    String[] arrayRecipe3 = { "chicken", "vegetable oil","unsalted butter",
            "sugar", "garlic", "sauce"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        String[] arrayItems = {"chicken"};
        String[] arrayVeg = { "vegetable oil", "ginger",
                "garlic","potatoes" ,"tomatoes","onion"};
        String[] arraySpice = { "roasted peanuts", "sauce","Dijon mustard" };
        String[] arrayDairy = { "breadcrumbs", "Parmesan cheese", "unsalted butter","sugar", "peanut butter" };
        spinner1 = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner1);
        spinner2 = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner2);
        spinner3 = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner3);
        spinner4= (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner4);

        spinner1.setItems(arrayItems);
        spinner2.setItems(arrayVeg);
        spinner3.setItems(arraySpice);
        spinner4.setItems(arrayDairy);

    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Items=spinner1.getSelectedStrings();
        veg=spinner2.getSelectedStrings();
        spice=spinner3.getSelectedStrings();
        dairy=spinner4.getSelectedStrings();
        Items.addAll(veg);
        Items.addAll(spice);
        Items.addAll(dairy);
//        for(int i=0;i<Items.size();i++)
//            tv.append(Items.get(i));

        compareArray();
        //count++;
    }
    public void compareArray()
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < arrayRecipe.length ; j++)
            {
                for(int i = 0 ; i <Items.size() ; i++)
                {
                    if((arrayRecipe[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((arrayRecipe2[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((arrayRecipe3[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        if(subset != null) {
            if ((arrayRecipe.length == subset.size())) {
                Intent nextClass = new Intent();
                nextClass.setClass(AddItem.this, TenIngreRec.class);
                startActivity(nextClass);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "arrayRecipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if ((arrayRecipe2.length == subset.size())) {
                Intent nextClass = new Intent();
                nextClass.setClass(AddItem.this, EightIngreRec.class);
                startActivity(nextClass);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "arrayRecipe2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if ((arrayRecipe3.length == subset.size())) {
                Intent nextClass = new Intent();
                nextClass.setClass(AddItem.this, EightIngreRec.class);
                startActivity(nextClass);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "arrayRecipe3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Un-Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // code here to show dialog
        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
        Intent intn = new Intent(AddItem.this,Exmain.class);
        startActivity(intn);
    }
  
}
```

and the major problem occured in this code which is array indexOutOfBound

```html
 for(int j = 0 ; j < arrayRecipe.length ; j++)
            {
                for(int i = 0 ; i <Items.size() ; i++)
                {
                    if((arrayRecipe[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((arrayRecipe2[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((arrayRecipe3[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

thanks again for helping me

Comment: I think you inverted i and j index... use j for arrayRecipe and i for Items

Answer (score 0):

array.Length() always count from 1 not form zero use 
**arrayRecipe.length -1** in your for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```html
 for(int j = 0 ; j < (arrayRecipe.length)-1 ; j++)
            {
                for(int i = 0 ; i <Items.size() ; i++)
                {
                    if((arrayRecipe[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((arrayRecipe2[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((arrayRecipe3[i].equals(Items.get(j))))
                    {
                        subset.add(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You're using the size of `arrayRecipe` to bound the index of `arrayRecipe`, `arrayRecipe2` and `arrayRecipe3` All three arrays are different in size, hence leading to your error. You need 3 different `for` loops, one for each `arrayRecipe`.
2. Your `i` and `j` are in the wrong places.
   `Items.get(j)` should be `Items.get(i)` as you are using `Items.size` to limit the size of `i`. Likewise, `arrayRecipe.get(i)` should be `arrayRecipe.get(j)`.

Also, it is true that `getLength()` and `getSize()` start counting from 1 rather than 0 so the index of the final slot is `(getLenght() - 1)`, but by using `<` as the clause in your for loop handles that.

Comment: Owen Ryan bro I used your suggestion but error is same on arrayRecipe3's condition. Can you recheck please

Comment: Like i said, the error is caused by you using arrayRecipe's size for all 3 arrayRecipes, as each one has a different size, so if arrayRecipe is bigger than arrayRecipe3, you'll get an outofbounds error. You need 3 separate "for" loops, 1 for arrayRecipe, arrayRecipe2 and arrayRecipe3.